# Facing trouble while sharing text, link and images together using intent filter

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am implementing intent filter to share some kind of information. But it is having a problem.

```
btnShareLocInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Location Name:" + locName.getTitle());
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, locName.getTitle());
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, locName.getDescription());
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getLocUri().toString());
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.image_url) + locName.getImage1()));
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
            }
        });
```

Here it displays title in subject and link but doesn't display title, description in text body.
Also on link click I would like to perform check if app is installed or not in phone, which doesn't work as well.

I have looked for similar problems but any of the solutions didn't work for me. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundle uses an ArrayMap inside for store info. If you use putExtra method more than one time with same key you replace the value.
Form doc of ArrayMap:

```
> /**
>      * Add a new value to the array map.
>      * @param key The key under which to store the value.  If
>      * this key already exists in the array, its value will be replaced.
>      * @param value The value to store for the given key.
>      * @return Returns the old value that was stored for the given key, or null if there
>      * was no such key.
>      */
```

So, concatenate info inside use putExtra for same key more than one time.
Like this:

```
String data = locName.getTitle() + locName.getDescription() + getLocUri().toString();

shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,data);
```

Instead for checking if an app is installed you can use this method.

```
public boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
isAppInstalled(myContext,"com.whatsapp"); // for checking whatsapp
```

Comment: Great. Worked in a no time. Thanks. After send What Do I have to add to perform check for if app is installed  after clicking on that link.

Comment: Do I have to add that inside shareButton onClicklistener?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad to help you